# A conceptual doubt on method of characteristic for solving a first order partial differential equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

This may be a very easy question of first order partial differential equation. I have a doubt.

We use method of characteristic in solving for first order linear and quasi-linear differential equations like $a( x,y,u ) u_x + b( x,y,u ) u_y = c(x, y, u )$. The characteristic curves is given by $$\frac{dx}{a} = \frac{dy}{b} = \frac{dz}{c}.$$ What to be done if any of the $a$, $b$ or $c$ be zero? Should we write $\frac{dz}{c} = \frac{dz}{0}$, when $c = 0$. It looks odd. In its theoretical proof we sometime avoid this case. Will the phenomenon be same weather $c = 0$ or not? Please discuss a little.

Please give me some hints for the problem related to above $y u_x + x u_y = 0$ with Cauchy data $u(0,y) = \exp(-y^2)$ for $y > 0$ and $u(x,o) = \exp(-x^2)$ for $x > 0$. How to set up the initial data with the problem in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take a curve, say **x**$(s) = (x(s),y(s))$. Set $z(s) = u(x(s),y(s))$ and consider $$\frac{\text{d}z(s)}{\text{d}s} = \frac{\text{d}u}{\text{d} s}(x(s),y(s)) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x(s),y(s))\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}s} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x(s),y(s))\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}s}.$$

Now if you ask $\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}s} = y$ and $\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}s} = x$, it is clear that (just using the equation) $$\frac{\text{d}z(s)}{ds} = 0.$$

Then your system of equation is
$$\begin{cases} \frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}s} = y \\ 
\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}s} = x \\
 \frac{\text{d}z}{ds} = 0
 \end{cases} $$

while the initial data are 
$$\begin{cases} x(0) = 0 \\
y(0) = y_0 \\
z(0) = e^{-y_0^2}
 \end{cases} $$

$$\begin{cases} x(0) = x_0 \\
y(0) = 0 \\
z(0) = e^{-x_0^2}
 \end{cases} $$

depending on the point $(x,y)$ in which you wish to evaluate your solution.